# How to fix "TypeError: Result of expression 'month' [undefined] is not an object"

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to run this javascript code and I am getting this error. The code runs inside a Rapid App Development tool that supplies its embedded javascript code runner with the values of the RAD tool variables surrounded by braces "[[ ]]" in the code. Here is the code below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < [[SAVED_COOKIES]].length; i++) {
var month = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.month
if(month.length == 1) {var month = '0'+month}
var day = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.day_of_month
if(day.length == 1) {var day = '0'+day}
var year = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.year
var hour = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.hour
if(hour.length == 1) {var hour = '0'+hour}
var minute = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.minute
if(minute.length == 1) {var minute = '0'+minute}
var second = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.second
if(second.length == 1) {var second = '0'+second}
var millisecond = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.millisecond
var time = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'T'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;
var time = _parse_date(time,"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss").getTime()
var time = time/1000;
var time = time+'.'+millisecond;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].creation;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].last_access;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires;
var secure = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].secure;
var httponly = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].httponly;
var domain = [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].domain;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].secure;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].has_expires;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].hostOnly;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].httponly;
delete [[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].session;
[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expirationDate = parseInt(time);
var regex = /^([a-z0-9]{1,})./gi;
var res = regex.exec(domain);
if( !res ){[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].hostOnly = false;}else{[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].hostOnly = true;}
if((secure).indexOf("0")>=0){[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].secure = false;}else{[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].secure = true;}
if((httponly).indexOf("0")>=0){[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].httponly = false;}else{[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].httponly = true;}
[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].session = false;
[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].id = i+1;
[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].storeId = "0";
[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].sameSite = "no_restriction";
}
```

I will really appreciate some help here because I have no idea what to do as I am not a Javascript person. Code used to work and all of a sudden the RAD tool got upgraded and now it gives this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future questions, could you please format your code? It makes it much easier for us to read. The online tool [beautifier.io](https://beautifier.io/) can help.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that `[[SAVED_COOKIES]][i].expires.month` is returning an empty value. Perhaps RAD changed their API and is storing month data in another field?

Comment: @MusicMan thanks!.. Will surely remember beautifier.io next time. Your suggestion is giving me an idea where to look. I will check that and see if that shows me the way out. Thanks!

Comment: @MusicMan, you were right..the api had indeed changed. Thanks